# File does not save in download folder

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, export-to-csv

I wanted to export the JSON data object to csv file and save it in download folder but I not sure where the file saved at or whether it has been saved or not. When i check the path it was written `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-192.168.1.14-csvproject/test.csv` and when i check the `FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path,csv,{ encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 })` it returns as

> Promise {
> "_U": 0,
> "_V": 1,
> "_W": null,
> "_X": null,
> }

```
CSV=async()=>{
        var data = this.state.results
        var headers = 'Transaction ID, Title, Amount, Category, Note, Date'
        var csv = `${headers}${data}`;
                
        var path = FileSystem.documentDirectory+"test.csv";
        var { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
        console.log("status:", status)
        if (status === "granted") {
        
       FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path,csv,{ encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 })
       var asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(path)
       await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false)
        
            
            console.log(`wrote file ${path}`);
            
        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use await and it return promise object instead of promise response

```
await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path,csv,{ encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 })
```

and then when you are execute CSV fn

```
await CVS();
```

Comment: if i execute the function when onPress i have to use await as well?

Comment: No but it will execute always as last in this handler

Comment: i just tried but I don't know if the file is written I can't find where the file saved as the folder is empty

Comment: Thanks Dawid for the reminder about 'await', I'd spent some time looking at "_U" etc and wondering what was going on (in my case it was using FileSystem.uploadAsync but the same solution applies).